# parameter from url adds in static directory path

Tags: node.js, express, static

When I try to `res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');` using express, first parameter `start` adds to the static directory path which then gives not found error.

here is my code.

```
app.get('/start/me', (req, res) => {
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

this is what happens.

**GET http://localhost:3000/start/static/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)**

But if I remove `/me` it serves fine.

route for handling statics files:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

on front-end

```
<script src="./static/jquery.js"></script>
```

I couldn't find solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your route for handling static files, but it seems you don't have one. All we see here is you serving `index.html`, but nothing serving `jquery.js`

Comment: I have updated the questions.

Comment: Show how you're including `jquery` on the front end. `<script ....>`

Comment: Check my answer, serve jquery from: `/static/jquery.js`, remove the dot (`.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're serving jquery from the wrong path.

According to your `/static` route, `jquery.js` should be served from:

```
http://localhost:3000/static/jquery.js
```

So your script tag should be:

```
<script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- instead of src="./static/jquery.js" -->
```

When adding `./` your script is not being served from the root, but is relative to the current url. So if you're in `/foo/bar/` it will search for `jquery.js` in `/foo/bar/static/jquery.js`

Comment: This solved my problem. But is there any other way to resolve this like `req.url` to chage url before sending file. ?

Comment: You're welcome. But I don't understand what you're asking. I don't now why you want to use `req.url` for solving something so simple like this, it will complicate things.